# Prove that there is such A, such that for each $x \in [0,2]:$ $|f(x)-x| \le A(x-1)^2 $.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ have continuous derivatives until second order in the interval $[0,2]$, s.t. $f(1)=f^\prime (1)=1$.

Prove that there is such A, such that for each $x \in [0,2]:$

$$|f(x)-x| \le A(x-1)^2 $$

SOLUTION ATTEMPT:

I know that:

- $\lim_{x\to x_0} f^\prime  (x)=f^\prime (x_0)$
- $\lim_{x\to x_0} f^{\prime \prime}   (x)=f^{\prime \prime} (x_0)$

I don't have any idea how to continue from here, any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Expand to a first order Taylor polynomial about the point $x_0 = 1$ with the (Lagrange) mean value remainder form.

Comment: I got that :

$|f(x)-x|= \frac{f^{\prime \prime} (1)}{2} (x-1)^2 + R_2 (x) $.

Now that seems so close to the result they want, but I still went to get rid of the $R_2 (x)$.

Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake. It's a first order Taylor expansion, with the mean value remainder form.

Comment: That way you get $|f(x) - x| = |\frac{f''(\xi(x))}{2}|(x-1)^2$.

Comment: okay, I got it, but its still an $equality$ between two sides, how do I justify the $\le$ ?

Comment: And $f''$ is bounded since it's continuous.

Comment: 100%. thank you so much!

Comment: $\xi$ is not a constant. It is just a number between $x$ and $1$.

Comment: and How do I guarantee that all what we did here is related to the interval $[0,2]$ only ?

Comment: I think that's only there because you need a closed interval containing 1.

Answer (score 0):

For each $t\in[0,2]$, the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that there is a $\xi$ between $t$ and $1$ so that
$$
\frac{f'(t)-1}{t-1}=f''(\xi)
$$
Since $f''$ is continuous in $[0,2]$, there is an $A$ so that
$$
\left|f''(\xi)\right|\le 2A
$$
for $\xi\in[0,2]$. Therefore,
$$
\left|f'(t)-1\right|\le 2A\left|t-1\right|
$$
For each $x\in[0,2]$, integration in $t$ from $1$ to $x$ yields that
$$
\left|f(x)-x\right|\le A(x-1)^2
$$